# Getting pid and other process information from /proc/<pid>/status

Tags: c, linux

I need to  get some information (pid is just an example, i know its much easier to get it in many other ways) from `/proc/PID/status`

I have tried to do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/procfs.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/param.h>

int main(){
        char buf[BUFSIZ], buffer[10];
        char pathbase[20], pathdir[20];
        FILE *fp;
        prstatus_t status;

        printf("Process ID: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Parent process ID: %d\n", getppid());
        printf("Group ID: %d\n", getpgrp());
        printf("Session ID: %d\n", getsid(0));

        strcpy(pathbase,"/proc/");
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", getpid());
        strcat(pathbase, buffer);

        strcpy(pathdir, pathbase);
        strcat(pathdir,"/status");

        if((fp = fopen(pathdir, "r")) == NULL) perror("fopen");
        fread(&status, sizeof(prstatus_t), 1, fp);

        printf("Proces id: %d\n", status.pr_pid);
        printf("Proces ppid: %d\n", (int)status.pr_ppid);
        fclose(fp);
}
```

and it obviously wrong, cause the result i get is:

```
Process ID: 5474
Parent process ID: 3781
Group ID: 5474
Session ID: 3781
Proces id: 1735289198
Proces ppid: 1733560873
```

Comment: Did you try from the shell `cat /proc/$$/status`? As you will see, it is a text file, not a binary one, so you should read one line at a time, and parse it as text. The `prstatus_t` here is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is `/proc/[pid]/status` is a text file. So your `fread` is copying text into the struct `status` - so everything will look like gibberish.

You could read the status file line by line or you could use the `/proc/[pid]/stat` file which contains the same information on a single line (`status` is for human consumption while `stat` is for program consumtion). To get the process id (or any other information) you would just have to tokenize that single line.